# Filtering arrays and adding elements together

Tags: arrays, swift

I read in a random text file I've created

```
hard        toffee        10
hard        toffee        20
...
chewy       gum           40
soft        marshmallow   20
hard        toffee        30   
soft        marshmallow   40
```

I create an array of sweets/candy objects and store it like this:

```
var candyArray = [
Candy(consistency: "hard", type: "toffee", cost: 10),
...
Candy(consistency: "soft", type: "marshmellow", cost: 40)]
```

Each object can be accessed through its properties:

```
print(\(candyArray[0].type))
// prints toffeee
```

I'd like to iterate through the array and if the consistency is hard, I want to += the cost to a variable used to store the sum of cost for hard candy.  I want to do the same with the other consistencies and then compare them to see which has the greatest cost when summed up.  Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.  Here's what I have so far:

```
struct Candy {
    var consistency: String
    var type: String
    var cost: Double

    init(consistency: String, type: String, cost: Double) {
        self.consistency = consistency
        self.type = type
        self.cost = cost
    }

}

var candyArray = [
    Candy(consistency: "hard", type: "toffee", cost: 40),
    Candy(consistency: "hard", type: "toffee", cost: 5),
    Candy(consistency: "hard", type: "toffee", cost: 5),
    Candy(consistency: "soft", type: "marshmallow", cost: 30),
    Candy(consistency: "soft", type: "marshmallow", cost: 35),
    Candy(consistency: "chewy", type: "gum", cost: 35)

]

print("\(candyArray[0].type)")

var x = 0
var largestValue = 0.0
var tempValue = 0.0

var currentConsistency = candyArray[x].consistency
var mostExpensiveConsistency = ""


while (x < candyArray.count){
    if (currentConsistency == candyArray[x].consistency) {
        tempValue += candyArray[x].cost
    } else if (currentConsistency != candyArray[x].consistency) {
        tempValue = 0
        currentConsistency = candyArray[x].consistency
    }

    if (tempValue > largestValue) {
        largestValue = tempValue
        mostExpensiveConsistency = currentConsistency
    }
    x+=1
}

print(" largest value: \(largestValue) and most expensive consistency: \(mostExpensiveConsistency)")
```

The code doesn't work when the consistency type isn't ordered like in the above text file I mentioned.  I was thinking of creating a 2d array or a dictionary and storing the consistency as a key and sum as a value for each consistency so that if the consistency appears again I can add it to the sum that was previously stored in an array/dictionary.  I hope I made sense. I'm just wondering if there's a faster way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce(into:)` to create a `Dictionary`, whose keys are the consistencies and the values are the sums of the cost of candies with that consistency. Then you can simply find the most expensive consistency type by simply calling `max(by:)` on the `Dictionary`.

```
let candiesByConsistency = candyArray.reduce(into: [String:Double](), { accumulatedResults, current in
    accumulatedResults[current.consistency, default: 0] += current.cost
})

let mostExpensiveConsistency = candiesByConsistency.max(by: { $0.value < $1.value })
```

The value of `candiesByConsistency` with your given example array will be

> ["soft": 65, "hard": 50, "chewy": 35]

And `mostExpensiveConsistency` will be

> (key "soft", value 65)`

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4's dictionary initializer can do most of the work for you.

For example:

```
let costs   = Dictionary(candyArray.map{($0.consistency,$0.cost)}, uniquingKeysWith:+)
let highest = costs.max{$0.value < $1.value} // ("soft",65)
let hardCost = costs["hard"] // 50
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it could be used this way.

Answer (score 1):

Swift provides some nice functions on collections for simplifying these kinds of tasks: `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`.

You could get the total cost of hard candy, for example, by writing:

```
let hardCost = candyArray.filter{ $0.consistency == "hard" }.map{ $0.cost }.reduce(0, +)
```

This does the following:

`filter`: returns an array with only items that match the specified condition (`consistency == "hard"`)

`map`: returns an array of just the costs from the `filter` result

`reduce`: aggregates a single result by performing an operation (in this case `+`) on all elements of the input array

You could do the same process for each type of consistency, or write an extension method that jut takes the name of the consistency you want, e.g.

```
extension Array where Element == Candy {
    func costOf(consistency: String) {
        candyArray.filter{ $0.consistency == consistency }.map{ $0.cost }.reduce(0, +)
    }
}
```

And then use it like this to get the value for each consistency:

```
let hardCost = candyArray.costOf(consistency: "hard")
let softCost = candyArray.costOf(consistency: "soft")
let chewyCost = candyArray.costOf(consistency: "chewy")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a dictionary to hold the cost summaries.
2. Iterate over the array of candies and summarize the costs, grouping by consistency.
3. Reduce the summaries into a single value, always choosing the pair with the greatest cost.

---

```
let candies = [
    Candy(consistency: "b", type: "b", cost: 1.5),
    Candy(consistency: "a", type: "b", cost: 1.0),
    Candy(consistency: "a", type: "b", cost: 2.0),
    Candy(consistency: "c", type: "b", cost: 3.0),
    Candy(consistency: "b", type: "b", cost: 1.0),
    Candy(consistency: "c", type: "b", cost: 2.0),
]

// 1
var costSummary = [String: Double]()

// 2
candies.forEach {
    costSummary[$0.consistency] = (costSummary[$0.consistency] ?? 0.0) + $0.cost
}

// 3
let mostExpensive = costSummary.reduce(("", 0.0)) { result, next in
    return result.1 > next.1 ? result : next
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This solution was interesting. I am quite new to swift and I was still unsure about how I could use the reduce function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice pipeline that can help you achieve your goal

```
let maxCost = Dictionary(grouping: candyArray, by: { $0.consistency }) // group candies by consistency
    .map { ($0.key, $0.value.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.cost }) } // compute the total cost for each consistency
    .sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 } // sort descending by price
    .first // take the first result
```

The result is an optional, this will give you an indication that you tried to process an empty candy array (unlikely but possible scenario), so you can handle that one too.

BTW, I couldn't help notice that you use `var` a lot, you might want to convert all those `var`'s to readonly ones (a.k.a. `let`'s) for better predictability and for better performance (the compiler can make optimizations if it knows that a variable is constant). The following struct declaration is identical to yours (memberwise initializer given for free by the compiler):

```
struct Candy {
    let consistency: String
    let type: String
    let cost: Double
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll keep this in mind.  Luckily xcode makes those suggestions to replace var with let but I will do this myself in future.